# Why is it important to minimize g-loading when dropping bombs?

Tags: dcs-world

I've seen mention of excessive g-loading (g>1.0) as a bad thing on an A-10 when doing a bombing run.  Shallow dives resulting in g-loading between 0.8 and 0.9 were ideal.  What bad things happen when there's excessive loading?  I'm looking for the direct effects of excessive loading.

Comment: are you running DCS-A-10A or A-10C?

Comment: DCS:World, A-10C

Comment: I made the game tag for you, let me know if you think the tag should be different than that

Comment: While I'm flying an A-10C, the question is general to all bombers.

Comment: so you want me to remove the warthog part of the tag?  I thought the whole game name was `DCS: A-10C Warthog`

Comment: ok, done (12 chars)

Comment: DCS-A10C is an older version. All the various games have been rolled into a single "world" called DCS:World.